# Displayed size of Go string variable seems unreal

Tags: memory-management, go, runtime

Please see the example: http://play.golang.org/p/6d4uX15EOQ

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    c := "foofoofoofoofoofofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo"
    fmt.Printf("c: %T, %d\n", c, unsafe.Sizeof(c))
    fmt.Printf("c: %T, %d\n", c, reflect.TypeOf(c).Size())
}
```

Output:

```
c: string, 8 //8 bytes?!
c: string, 8
```

It seems like so large string can not have so small size! What's going wrong?

Comment: A string is an array of bytes. If you want the size of the data, just use `len(c)`.

Comment: The `string` value you copy is a length and a pointer, not the actual stored bytes. See http://research.swtch.com/godata for more about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [Package unsafe](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/)
>
> import "unsafe"
>
> [func Sizeof](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Sizeof)
>
> ```
> func Sizeof(v ArbitraryType) uintptr
> ```
>
> Sizeof returns the size in bytes occupied by the value v. The size is
>   that of the "top level" of the value only. For instance, if v is a
>   slice, it returns the size of the slice descriptor, not the size of
>   the memory referenced by the slice.
>
> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Length and capacity](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity)
>
> ```
> len(s)    string type      string length in bytes
> ```

You are looking at the "top level", the `string` descriptor, a pointer to and the length of the underlying string value. Use the `len` function for the length, in bytes, of the underlying string value.

Conceptually and practically, the string descriptor is a `struct` containing a pointer and a length, whose lengths (32 or 64 bit) are implementation dependent. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type stringDescriptor struct {
    str *byte
    len int
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("string descriptor size in bytes:", unsafe.Sizeof(stringDescriptor{}))
}
```

Output (64 bit):

```
string descriptor size in bytes: 16
```

Output (32 bit):

```
string descriptor size in bytes: 8
```

Comment: > a pointer to and the length of the underlying string value; I can't understand this point.. Please, could you explain me in more details! From your words 8 bytes contain the pointer to the underlying string value and its length. Is it right?

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov: that's correct. A string is just a struct containing 1 pointer and 1 int.

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov: See my revised answer for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

A string is essentially a pointer the the data, and an int for the length; so on 32bit systems, it's 8 bytes, and 16 bytes on 64-bit systems.

Comment: If we assume that string descriptor are pointer to the data and underlying string size value. Is it means that max length of string at 32 bit system is ~4294967295 (max val of uint32) and 64 is about ~18446744073709551615 (max val of uint64).

Comment: Right in spirit--`len` returns a signed int (so max 2GB on 386), and of course if you actually tried to allocate a string quintillions of bytes long you'd run into some problems, haha.

Answer (score 2):

Both `unsafe.Sizeof` and `reflect.TypeOf(foo).Size()` show the size of the string header (two words, IIRC). If you want to get the length of a string, use `len(foo)`.

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/hRw-EIVIQg.